# Linespacing lost in Textbox

Tags: perl, hash, textbox, tk-toolkit

I've been trying to write a perl script which is supposed to read a file, parse it, display a brief summary of the contents (printed in set beginning and ending with a certain pattern) and display it in a report area when the user selects the summary of a certain set. I read the file line by line looking for starting and ending characters, save it in a hash with some other meta data that I use to build the summary. Then I tried creating a Textbox / ROText / Pane. However, when I try to populate the full contents using the insert command, all the spacing between the numbers is lost. This doesn't happen when I print the same lines into a file or onto the screen, the spacing is preserved. Can someone please shed some light on why this happens in the GUI? Here is an example of the file I am trying to read:

```
Assume that the file to be read looks as follows:

Starting report1
----------------------------------------
A B                   0.46    1.00  4.79
C                             2.00  8.54
DEF                   0.72          7.38
GH                            6.97  8.88
IJK                   7.46 8  6.98  4.32
End of report1


The GUI displays it randomly like this:

Starting report1
----------------------------------------
A B    0.46  1.00  4.79
C      2.00  8.54
DEF  0.72 7.38
GH     6.97 8.88
IJK   7.46 8  6.98  4.32
End of report1
```

This is the code:

```
my $summary_list = $summary_box->Scrolled("Listbox", -height => 5,-width => 120,-font => "7x13bold",-scrollbars => "ose", -exportselection => 1, -background => "black", -foreground => "white", -selectmode=>'single', -relief => 'groove')->pack(-side => 'left', -fill => "both", -expand =>1);
$summary_list->bind('<Button-1>', [\&retrieveReport] );

# Create the detailed text area, bind it to the summary list, configure the highlight text and disable editing
#my $report_area = $display_frame -> Frame()->pack(-side => 'top', -expand => 1, -fill =>'both');
my $report_area = $display_frame -> LabFrame(-label => 'Selected Path', -labelside => 'acrosstop')->pack(-side => 'top', -expand => 1, -fill =>'both');
my $report_entry = $report_area->Scrolled("ROText", -height => 30,-width => 120, -font => "5x5",-scrollbars => "se", -exportselection => 1, -wrap => "none")->pack(-fill => "both", -expand =>1);
$report_entry->tagConfigure( 'highlight', -background => 'lightgreen', -foreground => 'black', -font => "Arial 15 bold" );

sub retrieveReport {
my @sel = $summary_list->curselection;  
$report_entry->delete("0.0",'end');
$report_entry->insert('end',$display_paths{$sel[0]}{report});
#print "$display_paths{$sel[0]}{report}\n";

#Debug
my @lines = split("\n",$display_paths{$sel[0]}{report});
foreach (@lines) {
    #$report_entry->insert('end',$_);
    #$report_entry->insert('end',"\n");
    #print "$_\n";
}

# Highlight text
my @includes = $include_list->get(0, 'end');
foreach (@includes) {
    $_ =~ s/([\/\]\[])/\\$1/g;
    while ($display_paths{$sel[0]}{report} =~ /$_/gi) {
        $report_entry->tagAdd('highlight',"1.0 + $-[0] chars","1.0 + $+[0] chars");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think it is a variable width font that destroys the spacing. Try remove all font selections

Comment: Tk is badly broken.  Assuming you find a way to fix this font problem, you'll soon find many other frustrations with tk (layout bugs, file handle limit, lack of widgets, scroll wheel not working, etc).  If you're not in too deep, I suggest using Gtk (my favorite) or Qt.

Comment: You guys are correct. Removing the font configuration and using the default settings has fixed the spacing. That's very weird. I wonder how to get around this. I will definitely check out Gtk. It looks good. But I will see if I can find a decent solution. My widget is complete and this is the only thing bothering me now.

Comment: Tk doesn't have any layout bugs.  The scroll wheel is very easy to bind to the scrolling areas.  Why anyone would use any graphics package that doesn't have Tk's grid and pack manager's is beyond my comprehension.